# How to control content type menu options by group/permissions level?

Tags: permissions, custom, content

Working on a document approval project with doc libs.  We have different content types depending upon the type of user.  Ie- MembersA, MembersB, MemberC, etc.  I would like control the users content type drop down menu options by their permissions group.  MembersA would have a different ct menu than MembersB and MembersC.  MembersA will have different fields to fill-in than MembersB.

I've seen adding a CEWP and some javascript to read all the permissions levels then 'remove/hide' the menu entry but I was hoping for a more OOTB solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB way AFAIK.. Content types are structure, blue prints.. They don't come alive until you create a Document.. And in SharePoint you cannot set permissions on structures themselves.. Like if I can create a List, I can create an Announcement List, Tasks list etc. I cannot say User A can create Tasks list but cannot create Announcements List.. :)

However, I would suggest you make individual document libraries and set permissions on each document library.. This will help you not to put permissions on Content Types but actual Document Libraries themselves!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm afraid there's no OOTB solution for doing this.